# Differential of the restriction of a linear map on $\Bbb R^n$ to an embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ and $L:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is a linear map. Then the differential (which is a 1-form) $dL:\Bbb R^n\to T^*\Bbb R^n$ of $L$, is a section of the cotangent bundle $T^*\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$. We can consider its restriction $(dL)|_M:M\to T^*\Bbb R^n|_M$. On the other hand, the differential $d(L|_M):M\to T^*M$ of $L|_M$ is a section of the cotangent bundle $T^*M\to M$. If we consider the standard metric on $T^*\Bbb R^n\cong \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$, we can write $T^*\Bbb R^n|_M=T^*M\oplus (T^*M)^\perp$, and consider the projection $\pi:T^*\Bbb R^n|_M\to T^*M$. Then my question is : do we necessarily have $\pi \circ (dL)|_M=d(L|_M)$?